# Passing pointer to complex double in C (using complex.h)

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, complex.h

I am trying to run a function, `int testfn` below, which should assign a complex number to the pointer (to a complex number), `double _Complex *foo` below, that it is fed. The minimal (non-working) example .c file is `test.c` below.

**When I call `testfn` through `main`, instead of returning the assigned value `1.0 + 0.5*I`, it returns `0.0 + 0.0*I`.** I do not understand why, or how to fix it.

#### test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>

int testfn(double _Complex *foo) {
    double _Complex foobar = 1.0 + 0.5*I;
    foo = &foobar;
    printf("foobar = %.8f + I %.8f \n",creal(foobar),cimag(foobar));
    printf("*foo = %.8f + I %.8f \n",creal(*foo),cimag(*foo));
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    double _Complex toot;
    testfn(&toot);
    printf("toot = %.8f + I %.8f \n",creal(toot),cimag(toot));
    return 0;
}
```

#### compile and run with

```
cc -o test test.c -L. -lm -Wall
./test
```

#### terminal output gives wrong answer

```
foobar = 1.00000000 + I 0.50000000 
*foo = 1.00000000 + I 0.50000000 
toot = 0.00000000 + I 0.00000000
```

**Notice that the actual answer for `toot` should be `toot = 1.00000000 + I 0.50000000`.**

---

### On the other hand, this array case works

Here, in `test2.c`, I am feeding `double _Complex (*foo)[3]`, i.e. **a three-dimensional array of pointers to complex numbers (is that right?)** to `int testarrayfn`, and then assigning `foo` to be a specific 2x3 matrix of complex numbers inside `testarrayfn`.

When I call `testarrayfn` from `main` using `double _Complex toot[2][3];` and `testarrayfn(toot);`, I do get the right answer. **I am not sure why this is done right** (I just googled and played around a lot with arrays, and passing array arguments).

#### test2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>

int testarrayfn(double _Complex (*foo)[3]) {
    double _Complex foobar;
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<2;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<3;j++) {
            foobar = 1.*(i+1) + 0.5*(j+1)*I ;
            foo[i][j] = foobar;
            printf("[%d][%d]: foobar = %.8f + I %.8f \n",i,j,creal(foobar),cimag(foobar));
            printf("foo[%d][%d] = %.8f + I %.8f \n",i,j,creal(foo[i][j]),cimag(foo[i][j]));
            }
        }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    double _Complex toot[2][3];
    testarrayfn(toot);
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<2;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<3;j++) {
            printf("toot[%d][%d] = %.8f + I %.8f \n",i,j,creal(toot[i][j]),cimag(toot[i][j]));
            }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

#### compile and run with

```
cc -o test2 test2.c -L. -lm -Wall
./test2
```

#### terminal output gives expected answer

```
[0][0]: foobar = 1.00000000 + I 0.50000000 
foo[0][0] = 1.00000000 + I 0.50000000 
[0][1]: foobar = 1.00000000 + I 1.00000000 
foo[0][1] = 1.00000000 + I 1.00000000 
[0][2]: foobar = 1.00000000 + I 1.50000000 
foo[0][2] = 1.00000000 + I 1.50000000 
[1][0]: foobar = 2.00000000 + I 0.50000000 
foo[1][0] = 2.00000000 + I 0.50000000 
[1][1]: foobar = 2.00000000 + I 1.00000000 
foo[1][1] = 2.00000000 + I 1.00000000 
[1][2]: foobar = 2.00000000 + I 1.50000000 
foo[1][2] = 2.00000000 + I 1.50000000 
toot[0][0] = 1.00000000 + I 0.50000000 
toot[0][1] = 1.00000000 + I 1.00000000 
toot[0][2] = 1.00000000 + I 1.50000000 
toot[1][0] = 2.00000000 + I 0.50000000 
toot[1][1] = 2.00000000 + I 1.00000000 
toot[1][2] = 2.00000000 + I 1.50000000
```

---

### Additional questions about `complex.h`

I could not find the answers to the following questions anywhere:

1. Can one use `double complex foo` and `double _Complex foo` interchangeably, both inside a function, and an argument?
2. Can one use `double complex *foo` and `double _Complex *foo` interchangeably, both inside a function, and an argument?
3. Can one use `double complex (*foo)[3]` and `double _Complex (*foo)[3]` interchangeably, both inside a function, and an argument?
4. More generally, is there any difference between `double complex`, `double _Complex`, and `complex double`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test1

Two problems.

1. `foo` is a local variable. When you assign it it only will be valid in the function scope.
2. `foobar` is a local variable and it cannot be accessed after the function return (as it stops to exist)

You need to make `foobar` exist after the function return and pass the reference to the pointer.

```
int testfn(double _Complex **foo) {
    static double _Complex foobar = 1.0 + 0.5*I;
    *foo = &foobar;
    printf("foobar = %.8f + I %.8f \n",creal(foobar),cimag(foobar));
    printf("*foo = %.8f + I %.8f \n",creal(**foo),cimag(**foo));
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    double _Complex *toot;
    testfn(&toot);
    printf("toot = %.8f + I %.8f \n",creal(*toot),cimag(*toot));
    return 0;
}
```

or assign the underlying object with the value of the `foobar` (not reference)

```
int testfn(double _Complex *foo) {
    double _Complex foobar = 1.0 + 0.5*I;
    *foo = foobar;
    printf("foobar = %.8f + I %.8f \n",creal(foobar),cimag(foobar));
    printf("*foo = %.8f + I %.8f \n",creal(*foo),cimag(*foo));
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    double _Complex toot;
    testfn(&toot);
    printf("toot = %.8f + I %.8f \n",creal(toot),cimag(toot));
    return 0;
}
```

Test2 works because you assign the values to the referenced object, not trying to change the pointer to the array.

you can write the `foo[i][j] = foobar;` as `*(*(foo + i) + j) = foobar;` and it is identical as my second example (you can treat `toot` as single element array)

`_Complex` is an actual C keyword from C99 (or GCC extension before C99). `complex` is a simple definition expanding to `_Complex`. It is done this way as many old programs use its own `complex` type